# Can I always replace a translation together with a rotation with a rotation around some other point?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, proof-writing, soft-question, rotations

**Background / Context** The last days I have been implementing some affine transformation motion compensation for video applications.

[image]
[image]

left : original non-motion estimated sequence.
right : Index frame objects in black. Motion object in white.

---

**Question** : If I have a set of points in 2D plane which are subjected to a known translation and a known rotation (note : no scaling here).

Will I always be able to find some point which I can find some angle which I can rotate around which accomplishes the same motion?

In other words, can I make the translational part $0$ by before some rotation (which we once again are free to choose) making an arbitrary translation and then back again after the rotation ?

My **own thoughts** have mostly been focused around matrix representations for this motion and how I possibly can do linear algebra and factor things out. But any approach or proof or counter-example would be of interest.

Comment: Almost always yes. You have an orientation preserving isometry, which is a composition of 2 reflections. Unless the lines you are reflecting about do not intersect, you get a rotation. (and if they are parallel, then it's a translation)

Comment: Clearly, if the angle of rotation is zero, then the result is a pure  translation. Otherwise, consider the problem in the complex plane. Translation is addition by a constant number. Rotation about zero is multiplication by a number with unit norm. Any translation followed by rotation about zero is an affine linear function which can be rewritten as rotation about another point.

Comment: See this, for instance: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3112952/255730

Comment: Note: a translation by vector $\mathbf{b}$ is the limit a family of rotations where the center of rotation recedes in the orthogonal direction $\mathbf{b}^\top$ as the rotation angle shrinks. So you can think of a translation as a rotation of infinitesimal angle about a center point at infinity. All of this can be formalized using [projective coordinates](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Affine_transformation#/Representation).

Comment: @SammyBlack yes, great! Just as I thought. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is clearly...**no**.

Suppose that we have a non-zero translation composed with a rotation of angle zero. This (affine) map has no fixed point as it is a translation. If it would be equal to a rotation, it would have a fixed point. A contradiction.

Comment: But, if the angle of rotation is not divisible by $180^\circ$ then it is always the case.

Comment: Brilliant both answer and comment.

Comment: Ah, yes. Obviously. Then we would need to accept something like an "infinity point" to make it work, I suppose. Or to accept taking limits, moving the point of rotation at some pace out towards infinity and shrinking the angle of rotation at a suitable pace. Thank you. But in all other cases it seems possible.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is unclear. Here is my interpretation. Given a **non-empty** set $S=\{v_0,v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n\}$ of distinct **labelled** points and a rigid motion $f:v\mapsto R(v+t)$, where $R$ is a 2D rotation matrix and $t\in\mathbb R^2$ is the translation vector, do there exist a centre $c$ and a rotation matrix $Q$ such that each $f(v_i)$ is identical to the rotated image of $v_i$ by $Q$ about the centre $c$? That is, do there exist $c$ and $Q$ such that the following holds?
$$
f(v_i)-c=Q(v_i-c)\quad\forall i\in\{0,1,\ldots,n\}.\tag{1}
$$
We consider four cases. The answer to your question is **“yes”** in the first three cases and **“no”** in the last one.

1. $R\ne I$. Since the identity matrix is the only 2D rotation matrix with $1$ as an eigenvalue, $R^T-I$ is nonsingular in this case. Now condition $(1)$ is satisfied by $Q=R$ and $c=(R^T-I)^{-1}t$.
2. $f$ is a pure rotation ($t=0$). Clearly $(1)$ is satisfied by $Q=R$ and $c=0$.
3. $S=\{v_0\}$ is a singleton set. Then $(1)$ is satisfied by any rotation matrix $Q\ne I$ with $c=(I-Q)^{-1}\left(f(v_0)-Qv_0\right)$.
4. $f$ is a genuine translation (i.e., $R=I$ and $t\ne0$) and $S$ has at least two points. Since no rotation (by any angle about any origin) can map one *directed* straight line to a *different* parallel one with the same direction, the the answer to your question is negative here.

However, if the points are **unlabelled**, the problem becomes whether there exist $Q$ and $c$ such that $f(S)-c=Q(S-c)$. In cases 1-3 above, the answer remain positive, but in case 4, the answer now depends on the precise details of $f$ and $S$. For instance, when $f$ represents a translation to the right by two units, $f(S)$ is the rotated image of $S$ by 180 degrees about the origin if $S=\{(-1,1),(-1,-1)\}$, and $f(S)$ is not a rotated image of $S$ (by any angle about any point) if $S=\{(0,0),(0,1),(1,0)\}$.